# Different error response for different clients - Software Design/ Architecture

Tags: typescript, architecture, software-design

I have to create different error response for different front end (clients). Now I don't know how many clients will be there. I want to architect  this scenario in proper way. I have a created a prototype like following. Is this correct way of doing? Please guide me to select proper design pattern for this scenario.

Interface

```
IClientErrorResponseBuilder {
   getFailureResponse()
}
```

First Client

```
FirstClientErrorResponseBuilder implements IClientErrorResponseBuilder {

 getFailureResponse(e: Exception) {

   return {
    code: e.code,
    message: e.message,
   }
 }
}
```

Second Client

```
SecondClientErrorResponseBuilder implements IClientErrorResponseBuilder {


 getFailureResponse(e: Exception ) {

   return {
    code: e.code,
    message: e.message,
    reason: "SOME REASON",
   }
 }
}
```

From the controllers

```
import IClientErrorResponseBuilder;

// When instantiated, it will resolve dependency for ErrorResponseBuilder
class FirstController  {

    private errorBuilder;

    constructor(errorBuilder: IClientErrorResponseBuilder) {

        this.errorBuilder = errorBuilder;
    }

    public handler() {

        try {
            // do the stuffs

        }catch(e) {
            // If error
            this.errorBuilder.getFailureResponse(e);
        }
    }

}
```

// When instantiated, it will resolve dependency for ErrorResponseBuilder

```
class SecondController  {

    private errorBuilder;

    constructor(errorBuilder: IClientErrorResponseBuilder) {

        this.errorBuilder = errorBuilder;
    }

    public handler() {

        try {
            // do the stuffs

        }catch(e) {
            // If error
            this.errorBuilder.getFailureResponse(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Removed php tag.

Comment: How do you know which implementation you will be passed into the controller? FirstClientErrorResponseBuilder or SecondClientErrorResponseBuilder

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar new FirstController(new FirstClientErrorResponseBuilder );new SecondController(new SecondClientErrorResponseBuilder );